How can I create a button with custom shapes using only CSS (without clip-path)?
enter image description here
this is my button design and i want to create using only css.
"I tried using clip-path, and it works, but I want to create it using only CSS. Any suggestions would be appreciated..."
clip-path that i use:clip-path: polygon(0% 32.4%, 88% 1%, 88% 98%, 1% 78.43%);

clip-path is CSS

I don't see any reason to avoid clip-path. But another way to do it would be with pseudo-elements and gradient backgrounds.


button {
  --slant-height: 1em;
  --left-border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #f3f46a;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin: var(--slant-height) 0;
}

button, button::before, button::after {
  border-left: var(--left-border-width) solid #fdd748;
}

button::before, button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--slant-height);
  left: calc(var(--left-border-width) * -1);
}

button::before {
  top: calc(var(--slant-height) * -1);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(243,244,106,0) 50%, rgba(243,244,106,1) 50%);
}

button::after {
  top: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(243,244,106,0) 50%, rgba(243,244,106,1) 50%);
}
<button>Miss Smith Ellen</button>
<br><br>
<button>Mrs Annabelle McCluskey-Jones</button>




You can try  perspective property and rotateY()
Something like that.
<div> <button> Miss Smith Ellen</button> </div>


div {
  perspective: 40px;
  }

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f9d83c;
  border: none;
  transform: rotatey(-5deg);
  }

 

 


This changes the text as well, which is not what the OP wants (look at the image in the question).

use border-radius to create circular or oval shapes by rounding the corners of the button. after that Pseudo-elements (::before,::after), adding extra shapes to the button by creating additional layers that can be styled separately from the main element. Then Use borders to create triangles or other custom shapes by setting specific borders to transparent and one side to a solid color. You can combine these to create shapes without clip-path.
